# Aggregate tensorflow keras models

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0

Let say I have trained 300 different models, they all have the same architecture, only the weights are different.

Now, rather than calling my 300 models one after the others, how can I aggregate those models together so effectively having one aggregated X feature that would be fed into that model, and output results for the 300 model in one go?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you can ensemble them with functional API. But 300 models don't sound so practical.

Comment: As you said it feels like it's not going to be practical, also it will come with a massive duplicated internal code as all 300 models have the same architecture. Is there any way to leverage the fact that they all have this same architecture?

Comment: You would like to have 300 outputs at the same time for each these models or not? If you want one output, it would be easier.

Comment: I would like to be able to have all 300 output. And eventually, after adding a final layer.

Comment: You meant something like [this](https://3qeqpr26caki16dnhd19sv6by6v-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Visualization-of-Stacked-Generalization-Ensemble-of-Neural-Network-Models.png)? If you want individual 300 outputs then you need to define seperate loss functions etc for each of them I think.

Comment: Yes, all the models have already been trained separately, now the issue is how can I merge all those into one.

Comment: [This page](https://machinelearningmastery.com/stacking-ensemble-for-deep-learning-neural-networks/) might help you to gain intuition.